# Seagate 2TB external hard drive not showing up in Disk Management

Tags: windows-7, external-hard-drive

I have a Seagate 2TB external hard drive connected to my machine but this does not show up in Disk Management once I'm in Windows. I have tried this on both my desktop machine and my laptop.

Any ideas on how I can resolve this issue?

Comment: If the HDD in question is not showing up on multiple devices it means there isn't anything you can do, the device is broken, and the data is likely lost.  If you only care about the data, and are willing to void the warranty, then you can remove the HDD inside the enclosure and using a different enclosure to attempt to recovery your data.

Comment: Does it require a separate power supply or does is plug only into usb port? Have you tried with another usb cable?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as if your hard drive is failed and will no longer work. You will probably have to buy a new one and transfer the data to it. This data MAY be able to be recovered by someone who knows how.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the warranty, take apart the enclosure and plug the drive directly into the computer.

The enclosure can break but it isn't worth troubleshooting that since connecting the HDD directly is fairly easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me today (24/12/15). The disk didn't mount, but blue LED came on and disk spinning. I tried uninstalling the driver etc, but no luck.  Then I used Computer Management > Disk Management, which revealed a "Disk 0" (my system disk C:), and an unnamed "active partition".  I clicked on that with right mouse, assigned a drive letter, and up came the "Seagate Expansion" disk label.  The dialogue window -- that you get when you plug in a USB -- also appeared, prompting what to do (ie. open to view files etc).  So, all good now.

Comment: :- Welcome to the Superuser family and i hope you stay .... this answer does not really answer the question about his external drive not showing up in Disk Management and how to make it show up maybe with rewording it would provide help to him and others, thankyou